# Jquery plugin charcount with jquery form validation

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, char

I am using charcount plugin for a textarea

http://cssglobe.com/jquery-plugin-simplest-twitterlike-dynamic-character-count-for-textareas/

And jquery form validation

http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/

every thing is working fine but in place of error msg charcount is coming,hope so it is clear .Can any one help me over this problem.thanks in advance.a code example 
http://jsfiddle.net/rashvish18/gF7ua/1/

this is the code what I m using

```
$(document).ready(function(){    
$("#story").charCount({
        allowed: 250,        
        warning: 20,
        counterText: 'characters remaining: '    
    });
            //$("#storyform").preventDefault();

$("#storyform").validate({
rules: {

    place:"required",
            story: "required"

},
messages: {
    story: "Please write your story",
    place: "Please write your place"

},errorElement: "span",
    wrapper: "span" // a wrapper around the error message

});
```

});

[image]

[image]

Comment: show us your code. Or create http://jsfiddle.net and share the link

Comment: You probably referenced the error container element on the character count plugin. Code would be helpful!

Comment: here is the link http://jsfiddle.net/rashvish18/gF7ua/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this plugin has some bug,Finally I am using sm diff plugin ,that is working fine.

https://github.com/ndp/show_char_limit